# Ambiguity in Google's mail on Sheets API v3 shutdown March 3, 2020

Tags: google-sheets-api

The Sheets API team sent an email telling me they will shut down Sheets API v3. At the end they also tell me "Please bear in mind that after March 3, 2020, the Sheets v3 API will no longer be supported." What is left for them to not-support if v3 is gone? Or is v3 still usable but unsupported after March 3?

Comment: Contact Google directly to ask them about their services. We're not Google Customer Service. Questions about using the API are on topic here; questions about the future plans for the API or interpretation of emails are not.

Comment: Thank you, Ken. It's because I don't know how to contact them that I turned here. I only know how to contact API-users/developers. Then I thought I might just aswell ask around on SO. There are lots of SO-posts in similar cases, like the Google+ API shutdown, that weren't exactly "how to" questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact Google for an interpretation of their email and clarity on what their future plans are, because we can't speak on their behalf. Questions about using the Sheets API (code) are on topic here. Other questions related to it are not. It is irrelevant that you don't know how to contact them or that you're hoping to get an answer here - the site guidelines are not optional. Questions asked here must meet this site's guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

As they are just deprecating a version and not a service, I understand from this [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api?hl=vi) that v3 API is not going to be available from March 3 2020. Keep in mind that v4 was released a few years ago so there was enough time to migrate applications.

There is also a [guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration?hl=vi) to migrate to the new Sheets version.

Comment: Thanks, Jesca'. But what about my question? What do you think Google could possibly refer to as "no longer supported", once the V3 protocol is shut down?